# How to imply a specific number of bytes to a string slice

Tags: string, rust

Might seem like a dumb question, however, I've been trying to restrict a string slice (that comes as parameter to a function) to a number of bytes.

This is what I've tried

```
fn padd_address(addr: &str) -> Result<web3::types::H256, std::error::Error> {
  if addr.strip_prefix("0x").unwrap().as_bytes().len() > std::mem::size_of::<[u8; 20]>() {
    std::error::Error()
  }

  let padded = &format!("0x{}", format!("{:0>64}", addr))[..];
  H256::from_str(padded).unwrap()
}
```

Now assume I have an address like this
`let addr = "0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7";`. The function will firstly, strip `0x` prefix and after will compute the nb of bytes associated with the string.

Now if I were to `println!("{:?}", addr.strip_prefix("0x").unwrap().as_bytes().len())` I get 40 bytes in return instead of 20 which is the actual size of a contract address.

Any thoughts how I can check whether the string that comes as parameter, i.e `addr` has 20 bytes only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get 40 bytes in return instead of 20 which is the actual size of a contract address.

No, your address is

```
dAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7
```

which is in fact 40 bytes. `as_bytes()` simply returns the bytes data underlying the string, so it returns

```
b"dAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7"
```

it does not decode anything. Which incidentally makes it useless syntactic overhead as [it's literally what `str::len` does](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/str/mod.rs.html#157-159).

If you want the underlying value, you need something like the `hex` crate to decode your address from hexadecimal to binary (or hand-roll the same decoding), at which point you will have 20 bytes of data.